# Adding Event listener to drawn objects

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, event-handling

At the moment I am drawing rectangles using Windows Forms.

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black),new Rectangle(new Point(10,10),new Size(50,50)));
```

But I would like to add Event Listener to this so that I can make them moveable and resizeable.

Can I do this using Windows Form DrawRectangle() or is there a different way?

Comment: you want to add event listener to which control?

Comment: To the drawn rectangle

Comment: Please see [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469283/how-does-one-animate-a-line-on-a-canvas-in-c/15469477#15469477) of such a thing using current, relevant .Net Windows UI technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Panel`'s instead.

If you want them movable and resizeable - use `Form`'s. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319998/add-form-to-a-usercontrol-is-this-possible/7320094#7320094).)

<sub>(As for events for drawn objects like in your example - I don't know of a simple way to do that. But you can try calculating where the mouse clicked on the Form...)</sub>